# Send float[] to a server

Tags: java, android, apache

I want send a `float[]` in Java to my Apache server. I use Java API.

To send strings usually use `httpPost.setEntity` with `StringEntity`, but which "entity" do I have to use to send `float []`? Which is easiest way to send `float[]` to a my server?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`ByteArrayEntity`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/ByteArrayEntity.html):

```
ByteArrayEntity bae = new ByteArrayEntity(toByteArray(floats));

public static byte[] toByteArray(float[] a) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * a.length);
    for(float f : a) {
        bb.putFloat(f);
    }
    return bb.array();
}
```

You can read back the array using the [ByteBuffer.getFloat()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getFloat()) method.